# ApplicationContext is null for web application

Tags: java, spring, grizzly

We're building a web application and after the `HttpServer` is started I'm trying to load some items from the database into memory.  The best way I know how to utilize the service layer for this is to use the following class:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

It is continuously null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 8181);

    WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Socket", "/");

    //enable annotation configuration
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextClass", "org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    ctx.addContextInitParameter("contextLocation", "com.production");

    //allow spring to do all of it's stuff
    ctx.addListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener");

    //serve static assets
    StaticHttpHandler staticHttpHandler = new StaticHttpHandler("src/main/web");
    server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(staticHttpHandler, "/");

    //deploy
    ctx.deploy(server);

    //NULL
    WorkflowService workflowService = (WorkflowService) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("workflowService");

    server.start();
```

The service classes are annotated with `@Service` and my configuration class is...

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.production"
})
@PropertySource(value= {
        "classpath:/application.properties",
        "classpath:/environment-${MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.fettergroup.production.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {

    ...

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }
}
```

I believe something about this application using the grizzly `WebContext` is what is at the root of the issue.  But I'm unsure what to do about it.  I've done some Googling and it seems the solution I'm using should work...

Comment: As far I unstand the code the services will be available after 'sever.start()' as spring context will be loaded during server startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contextLocation` Init Parameter should be `contextConfigLocation`